# EF 4 Code First - How do I model this?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am trying out EF and Code First approach

I have an Account model which looks like

```
public class Account
{
   public virtual int AccountID {get; set;}
   public virtual string AccountName {get; set;}
   public virtual Account ParentAccount {get; set;}
   public virtual Contact AccountOwner {get; set}
}
```

Contact class is a simple class

```
public class Contact
{
   public virtual int ContactID {get; set;}
   public virtual string ContactName {get; set;}
}
```

Now I have no idea how to add IDs to the account class.

Suppose I have set up the context correctly, what modifications are needed to the Account class so that

1. I can add an Account as the parent of another Account
2. I can access the ParentAccount of a particular Account
3. I can access the AccountOwner of a particular Account

I am new to this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Unless you have a specific need, you shouldn't make the first two items virtual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would solve this.

Add foreign key properties to your classes. I'm talking about `ParentAccountId` and `AccountOwnerId`. To make navigating things a bit easier, I have also added a collection of child accounts to Account and a collection of owned accounts to Contact. Note that it's not necessary to make "normal" properties virtual. Only navigational properties should be made virtual.

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountID {get; set;}
    public string AccountName {get; set;}
    public int? ParentAccountId { get; set; }
    public int? AccountOwnerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Account ParentAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Account> ChildAccounts { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact AccountOwner { get; set; }

    public Account()
    {
        ChildAccounts = new List<Account>();
    }
}

public class Contact
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Account> OwnedAccounts { get; set; }

    public Contact()
    {
        OwnedAccounts = new List<Account>();
    }
}
```

Next, create a mapping for the Account class to explain to EF how to setup the relationships.

```
public class AccountMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Account>
{
    public AccountMapping()
    {
        HasOptional(x => x.ParentAccount).WithMany(x => x.ChildAccounts).HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentAccountId);
        HasOptional(x => x.AccountOwner).WithMany(x => x.OwnedAccounts).HasForeignKey(x => x.AccountOwnerId);
    }
}
```

Finally, add the mapping to your DbContext class.

```
public MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AccountMapping());
    }
}
```

Note that I have assumed that the AccountOwner and ParentAccount are optional. If they are required, simply change the type of the foreign properties from `int?` to `int` and change the `HasOptional` in the mappings to `HasRequired`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Account
{
   [Key]
   public virtual int AccountID {get; set;}
   public virtual string AccountName {get; set;}
   public virtual Account ParentAccount {get; set;}
   public virtual Contact AccountOwner {get; set}
   public virtual IEnummerable<Account> ChiledAccount {get; set}
}

public class Contact
{
   [Key]
   public virtual int ContactID {get; set;}
   public virtual string ContactName {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by without using Fluent API.That is by **default conventions** are maintained by EF.B'cos your mappings are simple.

You're having **Account (1) :  Contact (m)** Relationship.

So try with below models

```
public class Account
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string AccountName {get; set;}
      
   public virtual ICollection<Contact> AccountOwners { get; set; }
}


public class Contact
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string ContactName {get; set;}

   public virtual Account ParentAccount {get; set;}
}
```

Then Your database tables will be created like below:

```
Accounts Table

Id            int             NotNull
AccountName   nvarchar(100)   AllowNull

   
Contacts Table

Id            int             NotNull
ContactName   nvarchar(100)   AllowNull
Account_Id    int             NotNull
```

If you need to do advance mappings then you have to learn Fluent API.